# Shell namespace extension adding barricade

Tags: windows, winapi, explorer, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I implemented namespace extension using default shell view in **Windows XP**.
Everything works fine, but I want add barricade ([A Description of Protected Folders](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272963) - also applicable to Windows XP).
Is possible this using documented/undocumented functions (SFVM messages), or this feature is hard-coded ?

Comment: I'm not sure you provided sufficient information. If you fill all data for your extension view yourself, then you can read contents of hidden (or any other) folders on your own and display them straightaway, or hide if it needs to. Your extension uses its own namespace, which is not controlled by the built-in shell protection options.

Comment: My suggestion, don't bother researching XP. It's obsolete, unsupported by microsoft anymore and soon even vista will be obsolete.
Develop for windows 7 and up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you fill all data for your extension view yourself, then you can read contents of hidden (or any other) folders on your own and display them straightaway, or hide if it needs to.

Your extension uses its own namespace, which is not controlled by the built-in shell protection options.

**P.S.** Starting from Windows 7+ it should not be a problem.